# FM10420(fm10k) DPDK RX Queues become empty along with FUM_BAD_VF_QACCESS on dmesg

Tags: c++, networking, dpdk

I am developing my own dpdk application utilizing multiple rx/tx queues. My application runs perfectly fine with Intel 82599ES NIC. However, I want to run my application on FM10420. I use an FM10420 virtual function (VF) since my PF need to be bound to fm10k driver to control the switching fabric. Upon running my application on FM10420 VF, the RX Queues become empty after few seconds along with following two dmesgs on host computer,

```
[Nov23 10:41] fm10k 0000:b1:00.0: THI_MAL_DIS_Q_FAULT Address: 0xf0 SpecInfo: 0x0 Func: 00.1
[  +0.000251] fm10k 0000:b1:00.0: FUM_BAD_VF_QACCESS Address: 0x2f014 SpecInfo: 0x0 Func: 00.1
```

According to readme of fm10k driver,

```
Known Issues/Troubleshooting
----------------------------

FUM_BAD_VF_QACCESS error on port reset
--------------------------------------
A FUM_BAD_VF_QACCESS error may be written to the message buffer when a command
or application triggers a reset on the port's physical function (PF). When the
PF is reset, any bound virtual functions (VFs) can no longer access their
queues. This behavior is expected. No user intervention is required. After the
PF reset is complete, the VFs will be able to access their queues normally.
```

this behavior is normal and it happens when PF is triggered with a reset and VFs becomes unable to access their queues.
Also on https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/fm10k.html there is a mention about switch restart as follows,

```
19.3.2. Support for Switch Restart

For FM10000 multi host based design a DPDK app running in the VM or host needs to be aware of
 the switch’s state since it may undergo a quit-restart. When the switch goes down the DPDK app
 will receive a LSC event indicating link status down, and the app should stop the worker 
threads that are polling on the Rx/Tx queues. When switch comes up, a LSC event indicating 
LINK_UP is sent to the app, which can then restart the FM10000 port to resume network 
processing.
```

Hence my guess is the host interface or switch triggers a reset activity somehow and my application cannot detect it. I have tried to register LSC interrupts for my dpdk ports using rte_eth_dev_callback_register() function but could not register any events on my callback funtion.

However, I can perfectly run testpmd on this host with FM10420 VF using following command, utilizing multiple queues (without dmesg as well). Therefore I think testpmd has somehow solved this problem but I couldn't find any clues on testpmd source code which could be linked to this issue.

```
sudo ./x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/app/testpmd -c 0xffff -n 4 -- -i --rxq=4 --txq=4 --nb-cores=8
```

My problem is how can I solve this and where should I start? (By the way I have tried to enable debug mode on dpdk without any success)

```
Kernel Version - 4.4.0-190-generic
DPDK Version - 17.05.2
VF PCI Addresses - 0000:af:00.1, 0000:b1:00.1
PF PCI Addresses - 0000:af:00.0, 0000:b1:00.0
VF Driver - igb_uio
PF Driver - fm10k
PF Driver Version - 0.26.1 
Iommu settings - iommu=pt intel_iommu=on
```

Comment: Hi @Anuradha I have marked the question `as needs improvement`. This is because you have share the following information. 1) DPDK version 2) Firmware Version 3) VF PCI address 4) what happens if you `whitelist` and share `port mask` 5) what driver is bonded to vf port ?

Comment: Looks like you have already inforamtion, but not followed up https://community.intel.com/t5/Ethernet-Products/FM1000-quot-PMD-eth-fm10k-dev-init-switch-is-not-ready-quot/m-p/1210017/highlight/true?profile.language=ja

Comment: Hi, @VipinVarghese thanks for the response! I have edited the question with the information you have mentioned except firmware version since it did not shown up with ethtool -i. I am also not sure about "whitelist and share port mask". As per the thread on intel forum, it was also asked by me previously and fixed it using above iommu settings. I think it's not relevant to this problem?

Comment: I think it also need to be mentioned that, my application works fine with above FM10420 system using single RX/TX queues. Hence I think the problem is utilizing multiple queues.

Comment: DPDK 17.05.2 is not even LTS, please use 19.11 LTS isolate if it DPDK version issue. If you are using PF the dpdk driver will be fm10K_vf and not fm10K. Please confirm the same

Comment: Hi, I'm not using PF for my dpdk application. PF is bound to fm10k, not fm10k_vf I can confirm. The VFs are bound with igb_uio which will be used by my dpdk application. I need to think about changing dpdk version since it could introduce even more problems.

Comment: important question `before binding with DPDK did you check how many rxq txq are allocated from PF? if it s 1 DPDK can notmake it more than 1`

Comment: Yes I have check by binding VF with fm10k_vf. Each of VFs have received 16 RX/TX queues. Also as I have mentioned in the question testpmd works fine with these VFs utilizing multiple queues.

Comment: if testpmd is workign without isue. then what is the real question?

Comment: Requesting to update the ticket with proper information, and cleanup

Comment: Sorry if my question isn't clear. The question I'm having is my custom dpdk application cease to receive packets after few seconds after I started sending packets through it. rte_eth_rx_burst() returns zero. However my application works on 82599 cards. As I have mentioned above I need a guideline to how to deal with fm10k switch reset since I couldn't register any LSC events using rte_eth_dev_callback_register().

Comment: if you say testpmd is working fine with fm10K, then definitely the problem is in your custom application. You will have to isolate the same step by step. I have seen 82599 and X710 virtual Switch reset when error packets or incorrect size packets are TX out. So somewhere is your application code you might be trying to send invalid packet len or tx offload fields. (`FM10K does not support HW offload for VF`). This is not DPDK issue, hence I again request to refine your question

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I will do some more testing with my application and refine my question. This is the all information I got at the moment except the source code.

Comment: pointers 1. fix the question to focus on the code with snippet. and 2. start with `example/skeleton` if it works with f10K, check what is the difference. Note skeleton/l2fwd does not do any HW T offload.

Comment: Noted. Will do accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing few tests with `example/skeleton` and my own dpdk application I have found that the problem is with using `rte_eth_tx_buffer();`to buffer my packets to TX queues. I have replaced it with `rte_eth_tx_burst();` which will transmit my packets as single packet bursts. However, I guess this could affect my TX performance but I haven't done any performance tests yet.

I have no idea how fm10k have a problem with `rte_eth_tx_buffer();`. ( Maybe because of `FM10K does not support HW offload for VF`? )

**Update:**

I have found my mistake. I have used `rte_eth_tx_buffer_init(tx_buffer, 1))` instead of `rte_eth_tx_buffer_init(tx_buffer, MAX_PKT_BURST))` which essentially make only 1 TX buffer initialized. I'm not sure how it wasn't a problem on other NICs, but FM10420 certainly did.

Comment: dpdk `example/l2fwd` uses `rte_eth_tx_buffer`. with fm10K nic ports are you stating packets are getting transmitted with `l2fwd`?

Comment: @VipinVarghese l2fwd only use single RX/TX queues. rte_eth_tx_buffer works with fm10k if used with single queues. My application use multiple queues.

Comment: @Anradha, 2 points you mentioned the error is caused by `rte_eth_tx_buffer` this has nothing to do with multiple RX queue. you are alswys free to edit number of rx or tx queues. So please update with the findings with l2fwd as I suspect the conclusion you have shared `rte_eth_tx_buffer` is cause of error is incorrect.

Comment: DPDK API `rte_eth_tx_buffer` has same arguments as `rte_eth_tx_burst` with burst size as 1. Only difference is how things work internally, `tx_burst` immeadetly prepares the PCIe mmio operation for packet decriptros while `tx_buffer` buffer single packet at a time tilla  threshold is reached. Once reached whole packet descriptors are mmio to PCIe device. Important factor is port-queue has to be unique for each TX thread (you can not use the same TX queue for different thread). With respect to fm10K as pointed none of HW oflload works.

Comment: @VipinVarghese thanks for the explanation. I'll do some more tests with l2fwd in my free time and post the findings. I'm also not sure why it works with `rte_eth_tx_burst` and not with `rte_eth_tx_buffer` since both are mostly functionally same. Probably my code has a problem I couldn't identify.